# MediaSession onMediaButtonEvent works for a few seconds then quits - Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to listen to media button intents on this Bluetooth button I bought off eBay for the past week and cannot figure out how to do it practically and reliably on my Oreo device. The first thing I tried was overriding `onKeyDown` in my main activity, which worked perfectly every time. However, I found it was impossible to listen to these calls once the application is minimized.

Next I tried a very hacky solution of reading the logcat line by line and checking if `dispatched media key KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT` was present in that line. It worked alright until I again exited the app, which then it would completely stop.

Finally I tried using a `MediaSession` and the `onMediaButtonEvent` method, which works perfectly for a few seconds to minutes after I start my activity then it just completely ceases to receive these intents.

Here's my code right now (I copied another answer on StackOverflow who included playing a dummy audio clip to try and get focus):

```
        MediaSession ms = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName());
        ms.setActive(true);

        ms.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) mediaButtonIntent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
                        //do button specific stuff here
                    }
                }
                return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
            }
        });
        Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);

        ms.setMediaButtonReceiver(mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent);

        AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT), AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        at.play();

        // a little sleep
        at.stop();
        at.release();
```

I'm just trying to figure out now, why it seems to work for a few seconds perfectly, then it just stops out of nowhere. I don't have any other media app like Spotify open or playing whatsoever, and if that was the issue, I've tried running the audio code every 5 seconds or so which still has no effect. The only thing that will reset it is fully restarting the app.

This code is in a service I have created. It only stops working if I am not in the app and simply press the home button to minimize it after a few seconds. I have a loop running to tell me that the service is still running, and it's seems it's running when it quits receiving the intents.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code, it seems the bluetooth button press is only listened to by your app if music (or silent sound) is currently playing. Otherwise the button press is not detected.

Comment: You're right. I had to use a silent audio track played every 5 seconds or so to make this work. My app had only a small user base, so they were accepting of this solution :)