# Android MediasessionCompat callback function for physical media player button keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, keyevent, mediasession

I used the code from this link [MediaSession onMediaButtonEvent works for a few seconds then quits - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414333/mediasession-onmediabuttonevent-works-for-a-few-seconds-then-quits-android) to capture the keyevents of the remote button and send it to the audio() function where the selection will be played by another mediaplayer.

I run into the same problems where the code will crash after a few seconds.  I so far tried to do a loop and also made the audio track not to do at.stop() or do at.release but eventually it still crashes.  This keeps the service alive for a bit but then will still crash.  I have the code and logcat

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
    AudioTrack at;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MediaSession ms = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName());

        ms.setActive(true);

        ms.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent)     mediaButtonIntent.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyEvent.getKeyCode()) {
                      
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD:

                            audio("button0");
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND:

                            audio("button1");
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:

                            audio("button2");
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                            audio("button3");
                            break;
                     
                    }
                }
                return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
            }


        });
        Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);

        ms.setMediaButtonReceiver(mediaButtonReceiverPendingIntent);

        at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT), AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

       
       **//at.setLoopPoints(3, 10,10000000);
        at.play();
        at.stop();
        at.release();**
        


    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaSession.release();

    }



    public void audio(String command) {

        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();


        try {

            switch (command) {
                case "button0":
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button0);
                    break;
                case "button1":
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button1);
                    break;
                case "button2":
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button2);
                    break;
                case "button3":
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button3);
                     
                    break;
            }


            player.start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My logcat log

```
2022-02-13 19:08:01.568 19045-19060/com.example.medialistenercopy W/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaPlayer finalized without being released
2022-02-13 19:08:01.568 19045-19060/com.example.medialistenercopy I/MediaPlayerNative: setListener
2022-02-13 19:08:01.569 19045-19060/com.example.medialistenercopy I/MediaPlayerNative: disconnect
2022-02-13 19:08:01.580 19045-19060/com.example.medialistenercopy I/MediaPlayerNative: destructor
2022-02-13 19:08:01.581 19045-19060/com.example.medialistenercopy I/MediaPlayerNative: disconnect
2022-02-13 19:08:56.467 19045-19045/com.example.medialistenercopy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

    --------- beginning of crash
2022-02-13 18:57:56.595 17903-17903/com.example.medialistenercopy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.medialistenercopy, PID: 17903
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.example.medialistenercopy.PlayerService@e1c144e: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.release()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3880)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.release()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.medialistenercopy.PlayerService.onDestroy(PlayerService.java:114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService(ActivityThread.java:3860)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:208) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6991) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:884) 
2022-02-13 18:57:56.668 17903-17903/com.example.medialistenercopy I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17903 SIG: 9
```

Is the problem because the fake audio track ended too soon or because I have another mediaplayer playing sounds too.  I am tweeking everything I can.

I tried to tweek the audio track and I got

```
2022-02-13 20:58:55.609 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy V/AudioTrack: getMinFrameCount=3844: afFrameCount=1920, afSampleRate=48000, afLatency=80
2022-02-13 20:58:55.610 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy V/AudioTrack: set(): streamType -1, sampleRate 48000, format 0x1, channelMask 0x3, frameCount 3844, flags #0, notificationFrames 0, sessionId 0, transferType 3, uid -1, pid -1
2022-02-13 20:58:55.610 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy V/AudioTrack: Building AudioTrack with attributes: usage=1 content=2 flags=0x0 tags=[]
2022-02-13 20:58:55.619 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy W/AudioTrack: Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
2022-02-13 20:58:55.619 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy W/AudioTrack: See the documentation of AudioTrack() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
2022-02-13 20:58:55.625 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy V/AudioTrack: ~AudioTrack, releasing session id 8857 from 27560 on behalf of 27560
2022-02-13 20:58:55.626 27560-27560/com.example.medialistenercopy W/MediaAnalyticsItem: Unable to record: [1:audiotrack:0:-1::0:-1:1:0:5:android.media.audiotrack.underrunframes=1922:android.media.audiotrack.type=AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC:android.media.audiotrack.usage=AUDIO_USAGE_MEDIA:android.media.audiotrack.samplerate=48000:android.media.audiotrack.channelmask=3:] [forcenew=0]
```

Answer (score 1):

The specific reason for your crash is likely because you do not assign the field `mediaSession`; you've instead assigned an instance of MediaSession to a variable in a function scope inside `onCreate()`.

I would like to call out that we recommend handling the `onPlay()`, `onPause()`, `onFastForward()`, etc. callbacks from [MediaSession.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.Callback), as opposed to implementing `onMediaButtonEvent()`. The reason for this, is that not all actions are provided as a media button, such as seek commands, ratings or custom actions.

For more information about media sessions, see also my [contextual video on this topic](https://youtu.be/OYy41ceW59s) and [the dedicated codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/supporting-mediasession).

Comment: trying to use Callback to detect headset button press (during mediaRecorder). Tried mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(this, packageName) then mediaSession.setCallback(object : MediaSessionCompat.Callback() { override fun onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent: Intent): Boolean { Log.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent") return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent) })  mediaSession.isActive = true Unfortunately the callback never fires? Can you suggest anything I should try?

Comment: I suggest posting a new question to open a broader discourse than what fits in this comment section.

Comment: Paul as suggested I have created a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75092390/detect-headset-call-button-press-in-android