# Detect headset Call Button press in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-mediasession

How do you detect a user pressing the call button on a connected Bluetooth Headset?

While multiple posts address the topic I think I have tried most (if not all) and still have not found a solution which works

The following simplified code connects to the Bluetooth headset in onResume()

It then logs a message if ANY intent is received (which it never does)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var audioManager : AudioManager
    private var headsetDevice: AudioDeviceInfo? = null // device used for audio input

    private lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSession
    private lateinit var headsetButtonIntentReceiver:  HeadsetButtonIntentReceiver
    private lateinit var headsetButtonIntentFilter: IntentFilter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)

        audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        mediaSession = MediaSession(this, packageName)

        headsetButtonIntentFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON)
        headsetButtonIntentReceiver = HeadsetButtonIntentReceiver()

    }

    class HeadsetButtonIntentReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "HeadsetButtonIntentReceiver() !!!!")
            abortBroadcast()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val devices = audioManager.availableCommunicationDevices
        Log.d(TAG, "audioManager.availableCommunicationDevices found ${devices.size} devices")
        headsetDevice = devices.firstOrNull { it.type == AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO }
        if (headsetDevice != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setCommunicationsDevice ${headsetDevice!!.productName}")
            if (!audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(headsetDevice!!)) Log.d(TAG, "Failed to connect to headset")
        }
        mediaSession.isActive = true
        this.registerReceiver(headsetButtonIntentReceiver, headsetButtonIntentFilter)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (headsetDevice != null)
            audioManager.clearCommunicationDevice() // disconnect from the headset
        mediaSession.release()
        mediaSession.isActive = false
        this.unregisterReceiver(headsetButtonIntentReceiver)
    }

    companion object {
        const val TAG = "MediaButton"
    }
}
```

I have tried adding different Button actions to the intent filter - also without success

```
headsetButtonIntentFilter = IntentFilter()
headsetButtonIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)
headsetButtonIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON)
```

I have tried adding the intent into the Manifest (although several posts suggest this is not required)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have tried specifying the receiver in the Manifest - but also nothing

```
<receiver android:name=".MainActivity$HeadsetButtonIntentReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

For completeness I even tried overriding the onKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() but these are also not being triggered

```
override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown() KEYCODE $keyCode Event ${event?.action}")
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
}

    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent() KEYCODE ${event?.keyCode} Event ${event?.action}")
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }
```

Frustratingly there are indications the code is close to working. Specifically a double press of the headset call button dials the previous number but when the above code is running that no longer occurs indicating the App is consuming the call button press. Unfortunately the App is not being notified of this action!

Happy to try solutions posted in previous questions I may have missed!